# ValueError: need more than one value to unpack when parsing /etc/passwd

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I created a simple app where it prints a readable information of the output of `/etc/passwd`, but I get an error message after parsing most entries in the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unpacking_args5.py", line 19, in <module>
    uname, *fields, homedir, sh = user_info
ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack
```

Here's the code:

```
import subprocess

# the return command output is a string because
# of universal_newlines set to True
output = subprocess.check_output(
            ['cat', '/etc/passwd'],
            universal_newlines = True
        )

# this command converts it into a list of user information on the system
output = output.split('\n')

# --------------------- If this is the value passed there's no error ---- #
# output = [
#     'ianhxc:x:1000:1000:ianHxc,,,:/home/ianhxc:/usr/bin/zsh'
# ]

for line in output:
    user_info = line.strip().split(":")
    uname, *fields, homedir, sh = user_info

    print('Uname: %s' % uname)
    print('Fields: %s' % fields)
    print('homedir: %s' % homedir)
    print('shell: %s' % (sh or 'None'))
    print('')
```

Here's the output of the command:

```
Uname: root
Fields: ['x', '0', '0', 'root']
homedir: /root
shell: /bin/bash

Uname: daemon
Fields: ['x', '1', '1', 'daemon']
homedir: /usr/sbin
shell: /usr/sbin/nologin

# ... many successful entries omitted ...

Uname: mysql
Fields: ['x', '999', '999', '']
homedir: /home/mysql
shell: None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unpacking_args5.py", line 19, in <module>
    uname, *fields, homedir, sh = user_info
ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack
```

I'm thinking that it has to do with the use of "**star operator**".

Comment: Invoking `cat` from a Python script to read a file is quite possibly the most [useless use of `cat`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html) I have ever seen (not to mention a useless use of `subprocess`).

Comment: i'm pretty new to python, that's why there are a lot of bad practice in that script.

P.S. Thanks for the reference of the proper use of `cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lines without a `:` colon in them; when splitting these you get just *one* element.

That could be a line with a `#` comment on it, for example:

```
>>> line = '#\n'
>>> user_info = line.strip().split(":")
>>> user_info
['#']
>>> uname, *fields, homedir, sh = user_info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack
```

You can skip those lines; test the length of the `user_info` list:

```
for line in output:
    user_info = line.strip().split(":")
    if len(user_info) < 3:
        continue  # not enough fields to be valid
    uname, *fields, homedir, sh = user_info
    # etc.
```

Note that using `subprocess` is *overkill* here; you may as well just *read the file directly*:

```
with open('/etc/passwd') as output:
    for line in output:
        user_info = line.strip().split(":")
        if len(user_info) < 3:
            continue  # not enough fields to be valid
        uname, *fields, homedir, sh = user_info
        # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks,Yes `subprocess` is an overkill on this simple script. 

i'm also in the process of studying about `subprocess` module so i made use of it in this script.

Comment: I've inspected the file `/etc/passwd` and there's a line that looks like this `mysql:x:999:999::/home/mysql:`. That kind of line is the culprit since there wouldn't be enough fields on the user_info. 

Thanks again.

Comment: No, that line would work; `mysql:x:999:999::/home/mysql:` splits to `['mysql', 'x', '999', '999', '', '/home/mysql', '']` which is more than the minimal 3 elements.

Comment: @theUnknown777: it is the **next** line you had a problem with. Note that this also applies to *empty* lines.

Comment: Another thing i've missed out, why should there be a minimum of 3 fields instead of 4. Is the variable using `"*"` operators has a lower priority that those who don't. 

Does that mean, when using *multiple variable assignment*,  python make sure that those variable who don't use `"*"` operator get's assigned first and the variable who use the star operator is *optional*?

Comment: @theUnknown777: multiple means 0 or more here. Yes, that means that the `*` variable is the last to get values assigned to it.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters: thanks everything is clear to me now.

Comment: In the spirit of [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), I would `try` to unpack the tokens first and `except ValueError`, rather than checking `len()`.

Comment: Also, you forgot to bind the file object to a name and use it in the `for` loop in your last code sample.

Answer (score 1):

At the point of the error, `user_info` does not contain enough elements to assign to `uname`, `fields`, `homedir`, and `sh`. Put that assignment statement into a `try`/`except` block and have the `except` block print out `user_info` so you can find out what input is making it choke.

Comment: thanks, i was kind of thinking in enclosing them in `try/except` block.

Comment: Keep in mind that I only meant that for testing, so you can investigate the input and fix the error. `try`/`except` blocks should only be in your finished code to handle expected problems (like `int(input())`), not to hide bugs.